# How to get two columns from a SQL Server database and compare them with datatable

Tags: .net

I am trying to get 2 columns from a SQL Server database and then compare them with the Datatable but getting errors.

```
var distinctNames1 = (from row in dt_rev.AsEnumerable()
                      select row.Field<string>("Consumer_no")
                    .Distinct();
```

The `dt_rev` is generating datatable but I want two columns `Consumer_no` and `Paid Amount` and when it executes it matches with the data table and delete that record from files.

```
foreach (var nam1e in distinctNames1)
{
    // dtPayTrans
    DataRow[] results = dtPayTrans.Select("consid = '" + nam1e + "'");
    // DataRow[] results = dtPayTrans.Select("consid = '" + nam1e + "" + "paidamount = " + nam1e + "'");

    foreach (DataRow dr in results)
    {
        dtPayTrans.Rows.Remove(dr);
        dtPayTrans.AcceptChanges();
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
// Create Result Model
    var distinctNames1 = (from row in dt_rev.AsEnumerable()
                          select new dt_rev {row.Consumer_no, row.PaidAmount})
                        .Distinct();

    foreach (var nam1e in distinctNames1)
    {
        // Select dtPayTrans where consID is same as yourconsID and paidamount is equal yourpaidamoumd
        DataRow[] results = dtPayTrans.Where(x => x.consid == nam1e && x.paidamount == nam1e);
        foreach (DataRow dr in results)
        {
            dtPayTrans.Rows.Remove(dr);
            dtPayTrans.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have a modal of dt_rev in which the date from text file is shown.

Comment: ok , select new dt_rev if this is a model

Comment: dt_rev is not working with select as it says dt_rev is a variable and is used as a type

Comment: //create class 

public class dtRevModel {
public string  Consumer_no {get;set}
public string  PaidAmount {get;set}
}
after that , select new dtRevModel

Comment: still not solved but thanks for your time :)

Comment: you need dbcontext , I thought dtrev is a dbContext so was I wrong?

Comment: dt_rev is dataset from db and dtPayTrans is datatable. the code works fine when i apply above code i provided but it has one column of Consumer_no and if dtPayTrans entry of consumer_no matches with entry of dataset(dt_rev) of database it delete whole records as if there are 20 records whole 20 will be deleted so i have to apply another column named paidamount which will be then matched with dataset and if both of them matches it deletes that record not the 20 records.